# Auto scaling's scale in process with running Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, load-balancing, autoscaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

When auto scale process scales in and selects a node/pod to terminate, it gives some grace period for the HTTP requests that already entered the target node/pod so that HTTP requests gets time to complete processing and respond. Also during this period, the load balancer stops sending new requests to the node/pod which is about to be terminated.

My question is, what if there is a Kafka consumer in one of the process/container which is unaware that it's containing process is about to be terminated and it keeps consuming data from Kafka and processes. There are chances that process will be terminated while consumer in the middle of processing the consumed data.

So, is there any solution that let's Kafka consumer to stop consuming and give it some grace period for processing already consumed record? Similar to how grace period is there for HTTP requests?

*There could be some thoughts like, we can manually commit kafka offset after successfully processing it. But all scenarios may not fit for manual commit. May be we have to manually commit as soon as record is consumed and then process or just let consumer to auto commit.*

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages allow you to catch a SIGKILL/SIGTERM OS signal, which the container would receive.

From the signal handler, you could pause/close the consumer instance.

Keep in mind that you cannot scale a consumer application beyond the topic partition count

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. This thought makes sense. But I am thinking how can we make the autoscaler to wait for few seconds so that my application can complete the processing of already consumed message? May be we can handle it via manual commit to kafka. But still my use case assumes auto commit.

Comment: The autoscaling shouldn't terminate existing processes. If you are using auto commit, though, it might skip consuming events after a consumer group rebalance, but you can use a StickyAssignor class for that

Comment: My concern was when the auto scaling scales in the processes which were in the middle of consuming and processing a Kafka message.